# Is it possible to export Arrow functions in ES6/7?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

The export statement below gives a syntax error

```
export default const hello = () => console.log("say hello")
```

why ?

I'm only able to export named functions

```
export function hello() {
  console.log("hello")
}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: What does the error actually say?

Comment: Works fine here: http://astexplorer.net/#/0fv5UXttsP .

Comment: Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: The answer to your literal question is: *yes*. `export` doesn't care *at all* about the value you want to export.

Comment: I missed the default keyword. The error occurs if its the default export

Comment: you can only have one if you use default (per script)

Comment: I only have one but that stmt gives syntax error. The below works though export default hello = () => { console.log("why the downvote")}

Comment: what is the syntax error?

Comment: ERROR in ./src/redux/utils/ReducerUtils.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: ReducerUtils.js: Unexpected token (14:15)

> 14 | export default const hello = ()=> {}

Comment: You cannot name a default export.

Comment: Naming a default export is allowed for old style functions like export default function name1(…) { … } explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export 
Also splitting into two lines is valid: const hello = () => console.log("say hello"); export default hello;
Why would a one liner not be possible to export named arrow functions? I think for debugging this makes sense to trace back the responsible arrow function when these are named.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

> Is it possible to export Arrow functions in ES6/7?

Yes. `export` doesn't care about the value you want to export.

> The export statement below gives a syntax error ... why?

You cannot have a **default** export *and* give it a **name** ("default" is already the name of the export).

Either do

```
export default () => console.log("say hello");
```

or

```
const hello = () => console.log("say hello");
export default hello;
```

Comment: How does the below work then export default hello = () => { console.log("why the downvote")}

Comment: `x = y` is an assignment expression which resolves to the value of `y`. It's not a variable declaration. You can put `x = y` anywhere you can put an expression. **Note:** This will throw in strict mode if `x` is not defined beforehand.

Comment: what about regular exports ? is it possible to do something like: `export () => {/*body*/} as getUsers;` ? or do I have to first define it and then export it?

Comment: @Tomasz: `export const getUser = () => {...};`

Comment: @Burrich: It shouldn't matter how a function was created as long as it can be used in the way it is supposed to be.

Comment: "You cannot have a default export and give it a name ("default" is already the name of the export)." Not true, possible with: export default function cool() {
  return 'cool'
}

Comment: @Hans: I didn't mean to imply that functions need to be anonymous. I was referring to exports ("it" referring to the export). `export default var foo...` looks like a mixture of `export default ...` and `export var foo..`. The first creates a default export, the second a *named export*.

Comment: @FelixKling ah yes, I misunderstood.

Comment: for the second example, i like to do `export { hello };` that way you can import typed

Answer (score 53):

If you don't want a default export, you can simply export a named function with this syntax:

```
export const yourFunctionName = () => console.log("say hello");
```

Comment: So you replace `export function yourFunctionName () {` with `export const yourFunctionName = () => `. The characters length is the same, but there's a high chance to make a typo within this section `= () =>`. Honestly, to me it feels less readable and more work :)

Comment: Arrow functions differ with normal functions in how they asign `this` value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: why do we need const here?

Comment: @rahulKushwaha `const` is used to declare the variable, just like `let`, but in a way that you cannot change it afterwards. It used to be `var` in older JS. And `export` makes it available outside the file

Comment: so, export can only work with cont variable?

Comment: @rahulKushwaha it should work also with `let` but it is very rarely used. But `export` only without any keyword for variable declaration like `const` or `let` will not work

Answer (score 2):

Try this

export default () => console.log("say hello");

or

export const hello = () => console.log("say hello")