# I'm wondering why getting errors while in some cases while trying to export function

Tags: react-native

Why this error accrue, when trying to export default function

error: ReferenceError: test is not defined

just happens when :

```
export default test = () => {
    console.log("test");
};
```

while it works if

```
export default () => {
    console.log("test");
};
```

and also works if

```
const test = () => {
    console.log("test");
};
export default test;
```

Comment: nope, I tried that, and still getting error, thanks

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36459437/3001761

Answer (score 0):

You can either do

```
export default (test) => {
    console.log("test");
}
```

or

```
const abc = (test) => {
    console.log('hello')
}
export default abc;
```